# あなたにも as a response to someone's best wishes

Tags: grammar, set-phrases

I recently saw an exchange between two non-native speakers where one wished the other a happy new year, and the other replied with あなたにも (literally, "and to you").

Putting aside whether the use of あなた is appropriate, is Xにも actually idiomatic when returning someone's best wishes, e.g. 'happy new year', 'hope you have a great day' etc? It didn't feel right to me.

Taking 'happy new year' as an example, from a grammatical viewpoint, 明けましておめでとうございます has no target that takes に so I would not expect to see に in the response. However, just replying with あなたも feels wrong to me too.

Replying to something with "you too", "and to you" etc is very common in English. I wonder if あなた(に)も is actually natural in Japanese, or if there is some equivalent expression.

Comment: wouldn't こちらこそ work?  In response to something like 明けましておめでとうございます

Comment: What did the first person say?

Comment: @aguijonazo He said 明けましておめでとうございます, but I'd like the answer to be more general than this one phrase if possible, thanks.

Comment: Then there seems to be a misunderstanding here. 明けましておめでとうございます is not a phrase to *wish* someone a happy new year. It's a greeting that celebrates the beginning of the new year. There is no あなた (you), or こちら  (me).

Comment: @aguijonazo Fair enough. I hadn't thought about it that way. Nevertheless, it's still a phrase people say to each other at new year. Please forget about that phrase then and substitute with one which is a genuine wish. Maybe 良いお年を?

Comment: I meant こちらこそ in the sense of "likewisse", that is, I'm also wishing a happy new year or whatever other greeting the other offered.  Doesn't this work?

Comment: @A.Ellett - こちらこそ is like saying "I (= this side) am the one saying that (not you or more than you)." It doesn't work for 明けましておめでとうございます.

Comment: I am the one **who should be** saying that...

Comment: @aguijonazo  That is helpful.  I see now that I haven't been understanding こちらこそ correctly--close, but not accurately.  And now that I think about it, the semantics of it seem obvious.

Comment: @A.Ellett I understood こちらこそ to mean "it is I who should be saying that", with the suggestion that the person they are speaking to is more deserving of the earlier compliment/greeting. As in someone saying "thank you" and the second person saying "no, thank you". The context is of course that the person saying こちらこそ did not offer the compliment/greeting initially i.e. they did not pro-offer it like the first person did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's no phrase completely equivalent to 'you, too' in English.

First, I may be wrong, but 'you, too' is more often a response to a phrase where 'you' is a subject (Typically 'Have xxx' type phrase.). Considering the Japanese tendency to omit the subject, replying only with the subject should happen less often naturally.

That said, そちらも/そっちも/あなたも may work sometimes. For example, お元気で is a phrase literally meaning 'Stay healthy', used on the occasion of farewell. If the speaker and the listener are on casual enough terms (like old classmates), そっちも/あなたも do not sound too odd (the former more masculine, the latter more feminine; そちらも may be used, e.g. between the people who know each other by business).

Since there's some politeness implied in the situation where such phrases are used, it would be more common to repeat the phrase prefixing Xさんも, where X is the name of the speaker, if it makes sense. In the above situation, そちらも/あなたもお元気で can be used. For another example, when a person A says お気を付けて ('have a safe trip') to a person B, B can say Aさんもお気を付けて, assuming Aさん has some sort of travel. Otherwise people simply say ありがとうございます.

---

As for the particular phrases 明けましておめでとうございます/よいお年を, both *Happy New Year* in English, we just repeat them to each other, just like English uses *Happy New Year* to each other.

---

Another relevant phrase may be こちらこそ. When a person A says ありがとうございます or お世話になりました to a person B, B replies with こちらこそ meaning, ***I** thank you/It's you who did the favor* etc.